# Get room for each user in chat room application considering users access level

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii, yii2

I have two tables: room and with_access_room

```
id | name | access_level | image_id     --- room

user_id | room_id | token               --- with_access_room
```

There are 3 type of rooms:

- Public: everyone can see it (doesn't matter registered or not)
- Private: only registered users see it
- Private with access: only registered user can create and nobody can see it except creator which gets special token to invite other users.

Now in main page I have to show my rooms. Consider I have a user with id = 1. So he can see all public, private (without access token needed) and private rooms (with access) created by him.

In access_level column 0 is public and 1 is private.

For example:

room

```
id   |   name  |  access_level  |  image_id
1    |   aaa   |      1         |     1
2    |   bbb   |      0         |     2
3    |   ccc   |      1         |     3
4    |   ddd   |      1         |     4
```

with_access_room

```
user_id | room_id | token
   1    |    3    |  xyz
   2    |    4    |  zyx
```

So my user with id = 1 must see these "table"

```
ID | name | access_level | image_id | token
1  | aaa  |     1        |    1     | NULL
2  | bbb  |     0        |    2     | NULL
3  | ccc  |     1        |    3     | xyz
```

I am working with Yii 2

Which SQL query or Yii 2 model method with params can give me desired result ?

Comment: I don't see anything in your sample data which implies that user 1 has visibility to rooms 1-3.  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: user 1 is registered user so he can see all public rooms (with id = 2 in this case) , all private but not requiring token rooms (in this case id = 1 room) and private rooms with token requirement created by him (room with id = 3)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have described enough information to represent the problem.  Missing information:

- How is "Private with access" represented in the data?
- Where is the "creator" represented?
- How do we know who is registered?

I can guess reasonable answers to these questions.  In the end, the query will look something like this:

```
select r.*
from room r
where access_level = 0 or
      (access_level = 1 and
       1 in (select user_id from users u where is_registered = 1)
      ) or
      (access_level = 2 and
       1 in (select user_id from with_access_room war where war.room_id = r.id)
      );
```

This assumes that the creator has a row in `with_access_room`.

Comment: I can determine registrated user with Yii::$app->user->isGuest
Creator representation is requiret only for "with token access" rooms and is represented in with_access_room table (`with_access_room`.`user_id`)
Private with access is the room which access_level is 1 and id exists in with_access_rooms table

Answer (score 0):

This query should work:

```
select `id`, `name`, `access_level`, `image_id`, `token` from `room`
   left join `with_access_room` on `id`=`room_id`
   where `access_level`=0
   or `user_id`=1
   or `id` not in (select `room_id` from `with_access_room`)
   order by `id`
```